# about inject_events securityexception exception

Tags: android, exception, permissions

I am trying simulating touch tap by calling injectMotionEvent on a rooted Sumgsung P1000

I refer to the link :
[Android INJECT_EVENTS permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383401/android-inject-events-permission)
Although I successfully push the apk file to /system/app, I still obtain the INJECT_EVENTS exception.

Futhermore , I check my app's running priviledge and realize it's still running in non-root priviledge :

app_105   2814  2394  212416 23468 ffffffff 00000000 S

My question is : besides the items mentioned in [Android INJECT_EVENTS permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383401/android-inject-events-permission) , what else do I miss ?

Do I need to programmically to boost me to root , like :

```
try {
        Log.v("investigation","try to boost itself") ; 
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
      //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reboot");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("investigation" , "Failed to get su priviledge\n") ; 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Esscentially , this snippet doesn't boost me actually .

please help to enlighten me. Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only root permission is not sufficient for `INJECT_EVENTS`,
For that you have to sign your application with **firmware signing key**.

For an ordinary SDK application, you cannot inject events.

Comment: That's saying , I can't make an application that's general to all android platform. right .....

Comment: Yes, If you want to remove InJECT-EVENT part from it. Android never allowed it for ordinary application.