# Where does an event go when injecting it into /dev/input/eventx?

Tags: android, input, keyevent, inject, touch-event

I think I have read all post related with my query, some of them helped but I still can´t find the correct approach.

Im trying to develope an app which has to inject touch events into the system. As I was reading if you dont have system signature you can´t use the "logic" way, so we have to manage it using /dev/input/eventX.

Said that, I also attach photo of how events go through the system:

http://imageshack.us/f/201/eventosenandroid.png/

So I want to be sure that I understand how system manage events.

What I suppose is: When you inject a touch event in /dev/input/eventX the sequence for the event will finish into the activity which is currently "in the screen"

I just need to be sure if I can assume that it works like that or not really.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You managed to get somewhere with that? If not, did you have a look here?

[Android INJECT_EVENTS permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383401/android-inject-events-permission)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INJECT_EVENTS