# I want stop java.lang.security error

Tags: java, android, security

I am doing an Android application that has implemented a service.
This service launch some key events. In my main activity I implemented this function :

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent evento) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                stopService(new Intent(this, OpenCVService.class));
                finish();

            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, evento);
    }
```

to stop the service when the key is back, because if i don´t stop produce a security error.

The problem is that in some devices and sometimes the error appears again and is this:

```
08-02 15:53:47.486: W/dalvikvm(14873): threadid=16: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cad930)
08-02 15:53:47.486: E/AndroidRuntime(14873): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-373
08-02 15:53:47.486: E/AndroidRuntime(14873): java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
08-02 15:53:47.486: E/AndroidRuntime(14873):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
08-02 15:53:47.486: E/AndroidRuntime(14873):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
08-02 15:53:47.486: E/AndroidRuntime(14873):    at android.hardware.input.IInputManager$Stub$Proxy.injectInputEvent(IInputManager.java:356)
08-02 15:53:47.486: E/AndroidRuntime(14873):    at android.hardware.input.InputManager.injectInputEvent(InputManager.java:619)
08-02 15:53:47.486: E/AndroidRuntime(14873):    at android.app.Instrumentation.sendKeySync(Instrumentation.java:887)
08-02 15:53:47.486: E/AndroidRuntime(14873):    at android.app.Instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(Instrumentation.java:898)
08-02 15:53:47.486: E/AndroidRuntime(14873):    at com.uvigo.gti.PictoDroidLite.Control3$1.run(Control3.java:268)
```

My question is "How can i do to control this error?"

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android INJECT\_EVENTS permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383401/android-inject-events-permission)

Answer (score 0):

Write in your manifest file permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I try but produces this error "permission is only granted to system apps"

Comment: Only for rooted devices

Answer (score 0):

I've also been fighting against this.

In my particular case (probably yours too) the problem was the **lock screen in the emulator** was open when I was running the test.

This tends to happen when you wipe out the data of your emulator or some other circumstances.

Yes, that simple.

Hope it helps!