# How to use Xposed framework on Android emulator

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I am trying with API 17 and I'm unable to turn on [Xposed framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1574401).

Exact steps were:

1. Start emulator with partition size 1024
2. `adb install XposedInstaller.apk`
3. `adb remount` (make system dir writeable)
4. Launch the Xposed Installer and click on "Install/Update"

I get a *blank* error message and then it says framework is not installed.

Comment: Are emulators rooted by default?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd recommend Genymotion instead of the built-in AVDs. I couldn't ever get Xposed working with the regular AVDs.

http://www.genymotion.com/

Once you have a Genymotion virtual device created you can just drag-and-drop the XposedInstaller.apk onto the virtual device and it'll move and install the apk automatically.

Then it's just a matter of opening the Installer and clicking on "Install/Update" and voila, done!