# Trying to open camera App and take the pictures in my app

Tags: android, android-camera, adb

I am not an android developer. For some testing purposes on my application I had to create an app that turns on a camera and takes the picture:

I was able to achieve this by adb command such as following:

```
adb shell am start -a android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA 
adb shell input keyevent 27
```

Now, i wan this simple two liner logic in my app.

So I wrote the following code:

```
  //code to start camera preview intent
  Intent action = new Intent("android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA");
  action.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);       
  startActivity(action);

  //code to hit the camera button
  Instrumentation m_Instrumentation = new Instrumentation();
m_Instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA);
```

Now when I do that, I see the following errror:

```
Injecting to other application requires Inject-Event permission
```

While researching on that, i came actross following thread on SO:

> [Android INJECT_EVENTS permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383401/android-inject-events-permission)

i followed the instruction and added my app to the /system/ folder but facing the same issues.

Anyways, we can solve this issue?

I know on option may be to create an app with surface layout but I am not an android developer and I don't want to go that route if I don't have to.

Any suggestions on how can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you read [Taking Photos Simply](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)? Why not call camera app and press capture button by yourself?

Comment: Nope! That's not the option. I am writing an automation app...