# How to use espresso to press a AlertDialog button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-uiautomator, android-espresso

I want to press below button using Espresso, but I'm not sure how. Should I get the resource-id? Or how to set an ID to the AlertDialog??

[image]

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ApplicationTest {

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<LoadingActivity> mActivityRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(LoadingActivity.class);

@Test
public void loginClickMarker() {
//Doesn't work:
    onView(withText("GA NAAR INSTELLINGEN")).perform(click());
}
}

public class PopupDialog {

public static void showGPSIsDisabled(Context context, String msg, final PopupDialogCallback popupDialogCallback) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(context.getString(R.string.location_turned_off))
            .setMessage(msg)
            .setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.go_to_settings), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    popupDialogCallback.hasClicked();
                }
            }).show();
}
}
```

**android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is "GA NAAR INSTELLINGEN"**

Comment: I think you could use the withText() method instead of matching by id

Comment: onView(withText("GA NAAR INSTELLINGEN")).perform(click());
doesn't work

Answer (score 58, accepted):

According to `StackOverflow` similar issue: [Check if a dialog is displayed with Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045509/check-if-a-dialog-is-displayed-with-espresso)

You should change your code from:

```
onView(withText("GA NAAR INSTELLINGEN")).perform(click());
```

to

```
onView(withText("GA NAAR INSTELLINGEN"))
    .inRoot(isDialog())                 
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()))      
    .perform(click());
```

If it won't work, don't bother to use long with `Espresso` another great Google's instrumentation test called `uiatomator`.

Check: http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html

Example code:

```
// Initialize UiDevice instance
UiDevice uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());

// Search for correct button in the dialog.
UiObject button = uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("GA NAAR INSTELLINGEN"));
if (button.exists() && button.isEnabled()) {
    button.click();
}
```

Comment: This worked for me without the `check()` method.

Answer (score 11):

Since `inRoot(isDialog())` does not seem to work for `DialogFragment` I use this workaround so far:

```
enum class AlertDialogButton(@IdRes val resId: Int) {
    POSITIVE(android.R.id.button1),
    NEGATIVE(android.R.id.button2),
    NEUTRAL(android.R.id.button3)
}

fun clickOnButtonInAlertDialog(button: AlertDialogButton) {
    onView(withId(button.resId)).perform(click())
}
```

Comment: Thank you! isDialog() wasn't working for me, but I was able to find button1 and button2. Thank you for explicitly writing out how the different buttons line up with their ID numbers.

Answer (score 7):

For an `AlertDialog`, the id assigned for each button is:

- POSITIVE: `android.R.id.button1`
- NEGATIVE: `android.R.id.button2`
- NEUTRAL: `android.R.id.button3`

You can check yourself in the `AlertController` class, `setupButtons()` method.
So you can perform a click as follows:

`onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform(click());`

Answer (score 6):

You might need to close the softkeyboard like this:

```
        onView(withId(R.id.username))
                .perform(typeText("username"))
                .perform(closeSoftKeyboard())
        onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform((click()))
```

As detailed more thoroughly by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33489854/1313268).

Comment: I don't know if it's a new thing or not, but `androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions` has a method `closeSoftKeyboard()'

Comment: There is no need to wrap the `closeSoftKeyBoard()` call with `perform()` either

Answer (score 3):

The good thing about the last update is it allows you to set permissions before each test, so that you don't have to click the dialog (this speeds up testing by a lot!)

Use the following rule (e.g. for location/storage.. substitute these with the permissions you need obviously)

```
@Rule
  public GrantPermissionRule runtimePermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(
      ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

Answer (score 3):

In `AlertController` class, Android OS sets ids to AlertDialog buttons. Check the `setupButtons` method. At the time of this writing, for example, the positive button id is 16908313. So you can write something like this

```
onView(withId(DIALOG_POSITIVE_BUTTON_ID)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

where `DIALOG_POSITIVE_BUTTON_ID` = 16908313

It is also worked for me with the negative button

Comment: For me this the best solution.