# Click at (160.0, 120.0) can not be completed! (java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission)

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, robotium

When I tried to run some Android unit test, I kept getting

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Click at (160.0, 120.0) can not
>   be completed! (java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another
>   application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission)
>       at com.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickOnScreen(Clicker.java:106)
>       at com.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickOnScreen(Clicker.java:205)
>       at com.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickOnScreen(Clicker.java:170)
>       at com.robotium.solo.Solo.clickOnView(Solo.java:1096)
>       at course.labs.notificationslab.tests.NewFeedTest.testRun(NewFeedTest.java:41)
>       at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
>       at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
>       at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
>       at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
>       at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
>       at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)

Does anyone happen to know the reason and how to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Its a problem with permissions, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383401/android-inject-events-permission

Answer (score 1):

This is often caused if the soft keyboard is open and covering the item you are trying to click. I'd suggest making sure it is closed before continuing.