# Android virtual mouse cursor can't click outside the app

Tags: android, inject, mouse-cursor

I'm programming for a virtual mouse cursor by Android studio and that is from an example in this [website](http://www.pocketmagic.net/android-overlay-cursor/) and its [code](http://www.pocketmagic.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/myCursorOverlay.zip). I have an overlay cursor and following code to go back to the home screen.

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
newActivity.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
newActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(newActivity);
```

My problem is how can I apply the click action to my cursor when the view is outside my app (maybe home screen or other apps). I tried this

```
Instrumentation m_Instrumentation = new Instrumentation();
m_Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,new_x, new_y, 0));
m_Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, new_x, new_y, 0));
```

but it shown

**Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission**.

Then, I added
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"/>` in AndroidManifest.xml. There is an error called **"Permission is only granted to system apps"** so that I can't use it in my app to execute virtual click. If I just close the inspection system, it still doesn't work to my app.

After that, I tried **dispatchTouchEvent** with Handler but it only works in myself app (Can't be used in the home screen to open other apps.)

```
dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, new_x, new_y, 0));
dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, new_x, new_y, 0));
```

Thanks for your replying.
My simulated mobile device is Android 4.4.2.
Compile Sdk version: Android 6.0
Build tool version: 24.0.3

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  You're not allowed to for security reasons-  they don't want one app being able to send commands to another for security purposes.  THe instrumentation stuff is for unit tests, it works only because the test suite is part of the same application.

Comment: Thanks. If I root my phone, how can I open the permission of INJECT_EVENTS in my project?

Comment: You'd need to add the permission to your manifest, then install yourself in the system apps directory (depending on your version, either /system/apps, or /system/priv-apps).  Any app installed there can request system permissions.  So it won't work in a play store app, but it will be ok for a personal app.

Comment: I installed [this](https://kingroot.net/#) to root my system, then added INJECT_EVENTS permission to my AndroidManifest. However, it shown the same **Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission** in my debug window.

Comment: Did you install the app to the proper systems apps directory?  See http://www.androidauthority.com/install-user-app-as-system-app-how-to-93522/

Comment: I followed steps in the web, cut my app to system/app and then changed its permissions. In the moment, my owner and group is **root**. After reopening my phone and installed the app. It's error and crash again.

Comment: Should I create a system certificate? like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383401/android-inject-events-permission/7328055) but I can't find platform.pk8 and platform.x509.pem when I used Android studio and keytool-importkeypair.

Comment: @jarvuschen Did you ever figure out how to do this? I'm trying the same thing and getting the same exact errors

Answer (score 0):

you might find this link helpful :)

https://github.com/chetbox/android-mouse-cursor

it's without rooting and he managed to send clicks using those lines

```
    private void click() {
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("Click [%d, %d]", cursorLayout.x, cursorLayout.y));
    AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = getRootInActiveWindow();
    if (nodeInfo == null) return;
    AccessibilityNodeInfo nearestNodeToMouse = findSmallestNodeAtPoint(nodeInfo, cursorLayout.x, cursorLayout.y + 50);
    if (nearestNodeToMouse != null) {
        logNodeHierachy(nearestNodeToMouse, 0);
        nearestNodeToMouse.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
    }
    nodeInfo.recycle();
}
```