# Running Monkey Test on Mi Device Returning exception

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

Crash:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application 
           requires **INJECT_EVENTS** permission
```

Command:

```
adb shell monkey -p  PACKAGE_NAME -v -v --throttle 300
--pct-touch 40 --pct-motion 35 --pct-nav 0 --pct-majornav 0 --pct-appswitch 5 --pct-anyevent 5 --pct-trackball 0 --pct-syskeys 5 --pct-pinchzoom 5  --bugreport 100000
```

Any Ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: Try see answers here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383401/android-inject-events-permission

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After enabling Usb Debugging Under Developer Options .Please Enable 
USB Debbugging(Security settings) under developer options itself.

This worked for me !!

Comment: Yes, this setting for allowing input to applications is a bit lower in options then USB Debugging, 
For my Xiaomi phone it required Xiaomi account registration and 3 times confirmation.

Comment: i have a android 12, xiaomi note 10 pro, trying to send keyevent, and enabled the the same setting, still the same error

Comment: @DjWalkzz you've probably solved it, but restart your phone :)

Comment: yeah, i solved it by restarting phone :D